CKEditor 4 Does it support multiple paragraph tag indents?
I have a web application using CKEditor Version 4.16. We use most of CKEditor's features, including the indent feature in our implementation. This is done with the "Increase Indent" button on the CKEditor toolbar. One issue we've seen is the "Increase Indent" button works only once when indenting text paragraphs. The button remains selectable, but clicking it additional times does not increase the size of the left margin. Users can manually increase the left margin size/width by manually updating the HTML, but many users are non-technical who may have difficulty doing that. Is allowing only a single indent one of CKEditor's built-in limitations? Or do we need to add another plugin to fix this?
Our CKEditor implementation uses a plugin "indentblockdec". I've traced our supporting customizations, but based on this tracing it isn't clear if this plugin is actually used to support paragraph indentation.

This might not answer your question but I woudn't expect that button to indent incrementally without reselecting. Do any of the other buttons work that way?

We are re-selecting the button. I've tried it multiple ways - select button once and click multiple times, AND select/click once, then focus elsewhere, and then re-select and click. Same result - cannot add more than one unit of indentation.

Could you add a sample of the code you're working with to help others answer your question? *( a [mcve] )

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
